# ffmpeg input file options are not recognized

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am running this command in Ubuntu and windows but I get the full length instead of 10 mins. I want to split it in 10 minutes.

```
ffmpeg -i 2000.flv -ss "00:00:00" -t "00:10:00" -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac 2010.flv
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In what way it does not work? What is an error? Is there any error messages? What is the version of Ubuntu and ffmpeg?

Comment: Instead of splitting the file in 10 minutes chunk for the first run, It gave me the whole file as the output. I am using Ubuntu 10.04.
[flv @ 0x8469f74]Unsupported audio codec (a)
[flv @ 0x851d9fc]warning: first frame is no keyframe
thats the only possible error I can see

Answer (score 2):

In `ffmpeg`, [any command-line options that relate to a file must come *before* that file](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis). So, you should type:

```
ffmpeg -ss "00:00:00" -t "00:10:00" -i 2000.flv -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac 2010.flv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
ffmpeg ... -t 600 ...   # instead of -t 00:10:00
```

600 seconds is 10 minutes and I've had problems with the interpretation of the  hh:mm:ss format too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting it from the beginning you do not need the `-ss`. If you need to start it at a certain point put the `-ss` after `ffmpeg` and before the `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

the -t param refers to the length of part you want to cut. not the minute at it should end. 
If you have a 3 hour mix, and you want to cut it every 1h hour the commands should be:
1. ... -ss 00:00:00 -t 01:00:00 
2. ... -ss 01:00:00 -t 01:00:00
3. ... -ss 02:00:00 -t 01:00:00